# Prolog: sum the elements of a list

Tags: prolog

I am very new to prolog and I'm trying to sum the elements of a list.
So far, I have this:

```
     sum([],_,_). %base case
     sum([H|T], Y, _X):-
        X2 is H + Y,
        sum(T,X2,X2).
```

testing with sum([1,2,3,4], 0, X) results in an error, but I'm not sure what's wrong with this code. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What error are you having, specifically? What error message? I'm not a Prolog expert by any means, but I think your base case is wrong (maybe it should be `sum([E], _, _):- E.` or `sum([],_,_):- 0.`). Your summation algorithm also seems to use an extra parameter, but you might have a reason for that which isn't clear from this code snippet.

Comment: What does the middle argument mean? Note that `sum([], _, _).` means that if the first argument is empty, then the 2nd and 3rd arguments can be anything you like and it is considered true (succeeds).

Comment: @NicHartley Close but no cigar, both your ideas should be something like `sum([E], _, E).` or `sum([], _, 0)` as Prolog does not have expression/return semantics. As lurker rightly points out, there's no clarity on what the middle argument is supposed to be for.

Comment: @DanielLyons Well, like I said, I'm no Prolog expert -- I'm more used to similarly functional languages that _do_ have return semantics. I assume that it should be `sum([],_,R):- R is 0.` , or something closer to that, then? Though that still feels like it's using an extra parameter.

Comment: @NicHartley it's a little risky in general to assume that one language has the same semantics as another, and it's particularly risky with Prolog which is declarative not imperative. `is/2` is for numeric expression evaluation. So although `R is 0` works, it's not really intended as an assignment statement. Prolog's basic powerful functionality involves unification and backtracking. Predicates do not return values but rather either succeed or fail. In this case, `sum([], _, 0).` would be succeeds if the 3rd argument successfully unifies with 0.

Comment: @WilliamHennessy what do you suppose the middle argument is for? Usually the sum-a-list predicate has two parameters: one for the list, one for the sum.

Comment: @WilliamHennessy in SWI Prolog this doesn't give the right results but it doesn't error either. What's the error that you're seeing?

Comment: @lurker Very true, but I _did_ do some Googling before commenting. From what I understand, `sum([], R):- R is 0` would mean something closer to "if the first argument is `[]`, then `R is 0`" than "return 0", right? (though, fair, I didn't realize you could just put `0` there and have it automatically succeed)

Comment: @NicHartley It really means the opposite... *`R` is the sum of list `[]` **if** `R` is the arithmetic evaluation of 0*. And `sum([], 0).` is more accurately a shorter way of expressing `sum([], R) :- R = 0.` noting that `=/2` is the operator for *unification*.

Comment: @lurker Ah, okay. Cool! But as cool as this is, it's kinda turned into a separate discussion, so we should probably stop. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @NicHartley it was good to correct things for the OP's sake as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave is closer to working than you probably think, but it has a couple problems.

For one, Prolog predicates aren't functions, they don't return results like functions in other languages do. Predicates, instead, declare something about what is true. Later you can give prolog queries and it'll try to make them true.

For example, calls to [length/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) are true when the left argument is a list, and the right argument is an int with the length of the list:

```
?- length([1, 2, 3, 4], 4).
true.

?- length([1, 2, 3, 4], X).
X = 4.

?- length(X, 2).
X = [_2300, _2306].
```

Looking back at your first line:

```
sum([],_,_). %base case
```

This says "sum/3 is always true, as long as the first element is an empty list". You can test this:

```
?- sum([], -20, hello).
true.
```

That's probably not what you were intending.

I'm not sure how to put the rest of this without just giving away the answer, but look at what this clause is saying:

```
 sum([H|T], Y, _X):-
    X2 is H + Y,
    sum(T,X2,X2).
```

"`sum([H|T], Y, WhoCaresIllNeverUseThisVariable)` is true if we can recur and prove that `sum(T, H+Y, H+Y)` is true".

Well, one point, that last argument is a little weird, because in both clauses you assign it to an anonymous variable (`_` and `_X`). What you're saying is, "the third argument never matters and should match literally anything the uses throws at it". I don't think that's what you mean to say.

Second point, I don't know if you realize it but, you're actually computing a sum here! While trying to make `sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, X)` true Prolog will traverse the list and add each element to the middle argument, your accumulator. The summing part works! What you're failing to do is extract the sum from this predicate.

Generally in Prolog you "return" results by making them an additional argument. You could look at length/2 this way. Here's a way you might write it yourself:

```
my_length([], 0).
my_length([_|Rest], Length) :-
  my_length(Rest, Length1),
  Length is Length1 + 1.
```

This function "returns" the length of the array by only being true when the second argument of the predicate is the length of the array.